# How to get a formula cell from a sheet and change a variable of that formula for just one time?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I have a sheet that do a heavy calculation, with sums, factos and custom functions, that results in a single cell. Imagine a simple series of sums:

```
  | A   |
---------
1 | 39  | → This is my variable, everything else is fixed
2 | 800 | 
3 | 200 | 
4 | =Sum(A1:A3) |
```

In another sheet, I will like to get the result value of the formula on the Sheet1 A3 cell, however I will like to campare changes on one variable of that sheet, the Sheet1 A1 for that purpose

```
  |              A               |    B    |
--------------------------------------------
1 | =X(Sheet1.A4, B1, Sheet1.A1) |  40     |
2 | =X(Sheet1.A4, B1, Sheet1.A1) |  50     |
3 | =X(Sheet1.A4, B1, Sheet1.A1) |  100    |
4 | =X(Sheet1.A4, B1, Sheet1.A1) |  200    |
5 | =X(Sheet1.A4, B1, Sheet1.A1) |  1000   |
```

That will result in:

```
  |   A  |  B    |
------------------
1 | 1041 |  40   |
2 | 1051 |  50   |
3 | 1100 |  100  |
4 | 1200 |  200  |
5 | 2000 |  1000 |
```

So my question is, X function exist? how can I make it work that way? I Want to get the result of formula on the cell Sheet1.A3, however I want also for that case change the value of the A1 cell to get a different result.

Will appreciate any hint.

Comment: 1) On Sheet1, how does cell A2 change from 800 to 200? Should the formula in cell A3 be =Sum(A1:A2)? Or is the formula actually in cell A4?  2) On the other sheet, how does cell B1's value get changed from 40 to 41?

Comment: About 1) and 2), the numbering was wrong and the values to, it's fixed now. Thanks for notice! :-)

Comment: So you want to leave the value of 39 unchanged in Sheet1!A1, but you want to use the formula that is in Sheet1!A4, pass it a different value in place of A1 and get the results?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by having another sheet (or another data range in the same sheet) containing the possible values for A1 that you want to test, and then write a small VB macro that will:

1. Replace Sheet1:A1 with each of those values in turn
2. Recalculate Sheet1
3. Copy desired values (A1 and A3) into the relevant cells in Sheet2.